# Java dynamically generating various field types from a given array list

Tags: java, arrays, variables, dynamic

I'm trying to build a form generating class and i might have hit a glitch somewhere in my logic statement.

You have two string arrays.

```
String[] fieldNames;
String[] fieldTypes;
```

Both their lengths should be the same. Each value in the fieldName[] corresponds to a value in  the fieldTypes[] array.

I want to create various fields depending on the values stated in the fieldTypes array and assign the created fields the name specified in the fieldNames array.e.g.

```
String[] fieldNames = {"Name", "Phone", "Gender"}
String[] fieldTypes = {"TextFied","ComboBox", "RadioButton"}
```

The field types and names can vary. They can be whatever you want them to be.

Now, using the above info, how do i assign the fieldNames to the fieldTypes so I can use  them in the data processing? i.e

```
TextField name = new TextField();
ComboBox phone = new ComboBox();
RadioButton gender = new RadioButton();
```

I've been mulling this over for a week now and there doesn't seem to be any solution to this online. Or rather I haven't been able to find one. I someone could point me in the right direction i'll be greatful

Comment: Probably Map<FieldType,List<FieldNames>> is better than Arrays in this case

Comment: I second this. 2 arrays will be disjointed where as a map of some kind will allow you to link your names and types.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `Map` of `String` and `Class`, as such:

```
// This is for AWT - change class bound to whatever super class or interface is 
// extended by the elements of the framework you are using
Map<String, Class<? extends Component>> fields = new LinkedHashMap<String, Class<? extends Component>>();
fields.put("Name", TextField.class);
```

The `Map` is a `LinkedHashMap` so you can keep the order of the keys.

Once you retrieve a value through the `get` method, you can get the class of the desired component and act upon.

**Edit**

Here's how to retrieve the component through reflexion. Note that it's not the only solution and might not be the "cleanest"...

```
try {
    Component foo = fields.get("Name").newInstance();
    System.out.println(foo.getClass());
}
catch (Throwable t) {
    // TODO handle this better
    t.printStackTrace();
}
```

Output:

```
class java.awt.TextField
```

Comment: Thanks. let me give it a shot and get back to you.

Comment: @WandererofTime you're welcome. I've edited my answer in order to suggest one way (out of various ways) to retrieve the `Component` after your `Map` has been populated.